# Save the page state when navigating out

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Say I have two pages, A and B.

The user can modify things on page A then navigate to page B.
When he is on page B, he clicks the "Back" button to go to page A.
Everything that has been done previously is lost.

There is a way to get the exact same state by using

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = 
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

But is there a way to know whether the page is opened for the first time a by using the back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
  {
    // LoadPreviousSate...
  }
}
```

You also should've a look at `ApplicationExecutionState` (in `OnLaunched` event in App.xaml). If you navigate to Page B, Apps suspends, App continues, user navigates to Page A the `NavigationMode` will be `New`!

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to save things that I would like to reuse? (Some text that was not saved by the mechanism or something else)

Comment: You have to handle this by your own. If there is some text in a TextBox you want to save (and which is not saved by caching), write it to isolated storage or appsettings. You can also try to set  `this.NavigationCacheMode` = `NavigationCacheMode.Required;`