# Get a value back when navigating to a new page on a Metro-style app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

This is some kind of follow-up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413387/save-the-page-state-when-navigating-out).

Say I have a form that the user can fill out, with a ComboBox. 
There is a button next to the combobox. This button allows to go to a new page where the user can manage the items that were present on the combobox. If the user adds a new item and then navigates back, I want to select this new item in the combobox.

On Android I would use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to launch a new activity and get the new item back when the form page reappears.

How do I do that in a Metro app?

Comment: Please reserve the metro-ui to Metro design language related questions

Answer (score 0):

You can override the OnNavigatedTo method in the page and check for e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back to make sure that you navigated back from another page. Then you can check for changes in the content.

Comment: In the case of a ComboBox that is bound to an ObservableCollection and its content is updated automaticcaly, is there really no other way than using some kind of a hack to select the newest item? No way to get a value back from a page?

Comment: You can pass the view model for the ComboBox to the page where you add a new item to the collection and assuming the view model has a property that is bound to the ComboBox's SelectedItem property - you can update that property there. That way when you come back to the page that hosts the ComboBox - the new item will be selected.

Comment: Which completely break the concept of each page knowing only what it is supposed to know, and changing the interface on other pages. :/

Comment: Yes, but if the goal of your page is to serve other pages with a way to select/add items - then this is a dialog that does just that and it is its purpose. Otherwise you can play with an EventAggregator/Messenger type of solution, implement a custom navigation system or make your item-adding-control some sort of a dialog instead of a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a global variable in App.cs
before you navigate to a new page, assign the value to the global variable.
after you navigate to the new page, retrieve the value from the global variable.